# change the police/font-size in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi so i want to change the size of my answers but it's in javascript and i don't know how to change it because i can't change it in my css file.

```
let questions = [
    {
        question: 'Quel est la capitale de la France?',

        answers:[
            { text : 'tokyo', correct:'false', index:1 },
            { text : 'juin', correct:'false', index:2 },
            { text : 'ab', correct:'false', index:3 },
            { text : 'paris', correct:'true', index:4 }
        ]
    },

    {
        question: 'Quel est la capitale de la belgique?',

        answers:[
            { text : 'tokyo', correct:'false', index:1 },
            { text : 'juin', correct:'false', index:2 },
            { text : 'ab', correct:'false', index:3 },
            { text : 'paris', correct:'true', index:4 }
        ]
    }

]
```

Comment: What is the code you are using for displaying these?

Comment: its a javascript code for a Quizz on a webapp

Answer (score 1):

You can change the style of your text-fields like this:

```js
        let q1,a1,q2,a2;
        let questions = [
        {
            question: 'Quelle est la capitale de la France?',

            answers:[
                { text : 'tokyo', correct:'false', index:1 },
                { text : 'juin', correct:'false', index:2 },
                { text : 'ab', correct:'false', index:3 },
                { text : 'paris', correct:'true', index:4 }
            ]
        },

        {
            question: 'Quelle est la capitale de la Belgique?',

            answers:[
                { text : 'tokyo', correct:'false', index:1 },
                { text : 'juin', correct:'false', index:2 },
                { text : 'ab', correct:'false', index:3 },
                { text : 'bruxelles', correct:'true', index:4 }
            ]
        }

    ]
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",changeFontStyle);
        function changeFontStyle(){
            q1 = document.getElementById("question1");
            a1 = document.getElementById("answer1");
            q2 = document.getElementById("question2");
            a2 = document.getElementById("answer2");
            
            let fontFam='Helvetica,sans-serif';
            
            q1.style.color="#ff0000";
            q1.style.fontSize="20pt";
            q1.style.fontFamily = fontFam;
            q1.style.fontWeight="bold";
            a1.style.color="#008800";
            a1.style.fontSize="16pt";
            a1.style.fontFamily = fontFam;
            a1.style.fontWeight="normal";
            
            q2.style.color="#ff0000";
            q2.style.fontSize="20pt";
            q2.style.fontFamily = fontFam;
            q2.style.fontWeight="bold";
            a2.style.color="#008800";
            a2.style.fontSize="16pt";
            a2.style.fontFamily = fontFam;
            a2.style.fontWeight="normal";
            
            q1.innerHTML = questions[0].question;
            a1.innerHTML = questions[0].answers[3].text;
            q2.innerHTML = questions[1].question;
            a2.innerHTML = questions[1].answers[3].text;
        }
```

```html
        <p id="question1">question 1</p>
        <p id="answer1">réponse 1</p>
        <p id="question2">question 2</p>
        <p id="answer2">réponse 2</p>
```

Comment: @Nekreal 28
Please, let me know if this is suitable for your needs...

Comment: it does not work... nothing changed..

Comment: @Nekreal28 try "load" in place of "DOMContentLoaded"